# Why doesnt this program append the .mp3 file to music[]

Tags: python, python-3.7

So basically i had the idea to learn some tkinter and make a music player. It would have own folder/directory where music would be stored. I tried to create a program that sees only the .mp3 files no matter what the user put into the folder. heres some code

```
import os


filesInDir = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\kapro\\desktop\\music') #gets all files from directory
print(filesInDir)
music = []


for i in filesInDir: 
    print(i) 
    if i[-4:] == #'.mp3'.lower: #check if last 4 chars of the filename is .mp3
        print(i) 
        music.append(i) # and if so, append this filename to music[]


print(music)
```

But it never adds the file to music[]

i tried everything i could think of, i cant figure out whats wrong.
also i dont want to literally use Ctrl + C - Ctrl + V because i want to get something out of this project

Comment: `if i[-4:] == #'.mp3'.lower: #check` isn't valid syntax. Can you paste what you ran? Also did you mean to do `.lower()` instead of `.lower`?

Comment: And shouldn't the `lower` part be on the opposite side?

Comment: ^ That too. I saw that but forgot to comment.

Comment: Thanks guys, i really appreciate for ur help, just seems like it was my fault. first of i did lower instead of lower() and put lower not in the place it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like to never actually call the `lower()` function (the parentheses are what actually calls the method). Also you have it on the wrong side.

Try this for your `if` statement:

```
if i[-4:].lower() == ".mp3":
```

Comment: This is the answers section. That is a question. If you want to ask for clarification, comment. If you don't have enough rep to comment please don't use the answers section for it

Comment: I don't have enough rep to use comment section, but though even if it's a question, it's a rhetorical one. Thanks for lowering my rep, so I'll never be able to use this comment section.

Comment: Was answering to Tomerikoo. ^^' I don't really care about rep, i'm just trying to help :p

Comment: Hi @JonathanvonTamer my comment was genuinly because it seemed as if you're asking. This probably does solve the problem, just try to be more clear. In general try not to answer unclear questions and also it's nice to add some explanations to don't have code-only answers. Didn't mean no harm :) keep helping other coders